# question related to django models

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I'm building simple shopping website for learning purpose only. I wrote following messy models. Is there any problem in my models? Please point out me. thanks you so much. :-)

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=155)
    description = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photo',blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=300,)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)

class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product',related_name='product_details')
    pages = models.CharFields(max_length=4)
    language = models.CharFields(max_length=50)
    binding = models.CharFields(max_length=50)

class Author(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  email = models.EmailField()
```

Comment: since you are only asking about code editing without having any specific errors or questions stated, this sort of question is probably better put on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product.author` should be a `ForeignKey` to `Author`, you have a useless comma at `Product.author`, and your `Product.name` and `Product.slug` have different lengths, when they contain (or should contain) almost the same data. Also, instead of the `Author` model you could use the builtin `User` model. Other than that, it seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

In `ProductDetail`, the models for pages, language, and binding should be `CharField` not `CharFields` with an `s`